# How to check if current date is same as date from list of dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, for example, I got 3 dates:

- 2020-07-14
- 2020-07-16
- 2020-07-15

If any of dates matches current date(2020-07-16), i should display values for that day.
This is code i wrote, but every time i reload the page, other value is being displayed
:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.pen_feeding_scheduler_list.length; i++) {
      if (response.pen_feeding_scheduler_list[i].feeding_frequency_rule) {
         vm.feed_date_start = response.pen_feeding_scheduler_list[i].start_feeding_date;
         var current_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      if (current_date == vm.feed_date_start) {
         vm.dateSet = true;
      } else if (moment(vm.feed_date_start).isBefore(current_date)) {
         vm.dateSet = true;
      } else if (moment(vm.feed_date_start).isAfter(current_date)) {
         vm.dateSet = false;
      }
        if (vm.dateSet) {
        response.feeding_frequency = getFrequency(response.pen_feeding_scheduler_list[i].feeding_frequency_rule);
         }
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

- Format current date as string
- simply compare two strings

```js
const dates = ['2020-07-14', '2020-07-16', '2020-07-15'];

console.log(
  dates.includes(
        new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
  )
);
```

Comment: `var current_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)` aint that what he is doing?

Comment: Do you know how could I get the closest date in the past from the current date which will match to these dates, if current date doesn't match with any of these dates?

Comment: Sure, get ```dates``` array, change them to milliseconds timestamp.
Change current date to milliseconds too. Create diffs array. Then just sort array, and get smallest diff. Easy

Answer (score 0):

I think you should approach it in the opposite direction, instead of formatting current date to received date format (YYYY-MM-DD), just format those dates into timestamp.

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(0)
currentDate.setMinutes(-currentDate.getTimezoneOffset())
currentDate.setSeconds(0)
currentDate.setMilliseconds(0)


const currentTimestamp = currentDate.getTime(); // transforming date into universal timestamp
console.log(currentTimestamp === new Date("2020-07-14").getTime());
console.log(currentTimestamp === new Date("2020-07-16").getTime());
```